# Auto-layout mangles the segues in the iPad version

Tags: objective-c, ipad, autolayout, segue

After a number of tests I found that a normal working iPad storyboard starts working weirdly upon introducing auto-layout. In particular it seems not to properly pop-up dismissed views by always recycling the same view controller and to also badly handle the queue of instantiated view controllers. When I disable auto-layout everything works fine again. Does anyone know if this bug is known to Apple or there is a fix?

Comment: Caro fabrizio, what's the problem with the rows? personally i don't like nor storyboard nor autolayout, it's best to code everything. but frm what i know, no there's no known bug like that :)

Comment: I have been using storyboards since long and auto layout just for the iPad version until now. And I ad no problem whatsoever. Yet I do not know how you may help me if you use neither.

Comment: Have you set the constrain properly ?

Comment: The problem does not occur in constraints, they are quite vocal when there is something wrong in fact. It happens when I click somewhere activating a segue. I agree that there should not be any connection between the issues, and that is the reason why I took nearly two days to find the association.

Answer (score 0):

Not been able to complement the question with new information, I posted a new one at:
[Triggering segues from annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007644/triggering-segues-from-annotations)